# MFA support for Azure VM connect using Remote desktop

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, multi-factor-authentication

We have planned to enable MFA for Azure VM.  We need to know the possibilities for achieve the MFA while connect the Azure VM using Remote desktop connection.

Questions:

1. Can we achieve the MFA Security authentication for Azure VM using RDP?
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/multi-factor-authentication
2. Is there any Step by step functional tutorials to enable MFA for Azure VM?

Regards,
Mathan Kumar

Answer (score 2):

1.Yes,if you use a remote desktop gateway, then you can enable MFA on Azure VM when logging into VM via RDP.

2.You may refer the link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfaserver-nps-rdg